# Error converting string to DateTime

Tags: c#, date

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       if (ValidateInput())
       {
          if (md.NAME_ID("LOGIN", "UID", "UNAME", UserNameTextBox.Text) != "")
          {
              MessageBox.Show("User already exist");
              return;
          }
          string PASS = "";
          if (UpassTextBox.Text != "")
          {
              PASS = base64Encode(UpassTextBox.Text);
          }
          else
          {
             PASS = "";
          }
          LoginTbl login = new LoginTbl(Convert.ToString(md.Max_ID("UID", "LOGIN")),
                               Convert.ToDateTime(DT1.Value.ToShortDateString()), 
                               Convert.ToBoolean(ActiveRadioButton.Checked ? true : false), 
                               UserNameTextBox.Text, PASS, MobileTextBox.Text, 
                               RemarksTextBox.Text, UpdateCheckBox.Checked, 
                               DeleteCheckBox.Checked, MenuCheckBox.Checked, 
                               AddItemCheckBox.Checked, SearchItemCheckBox.Checked, 
                               ListViewCheckBox.Checked, PurchaseCheckBox.Checked, 
                               PurReturnCheckBox.Checked, PurPerformaCheckBox.Checked, 
                               PurImportsCheckBox.Checked, PurReportsCheckBox.Checked, 
                               SaleCheckBox.Checked, SaleReturnCheckBox.Checked, 
                               SalePerformaCheckBox.Checked, SaleReportsCheckBox.Checked, 
                               InventoryCheckBox.Checked, PaymentCheckBox.Checked, 
                               JVCheckBox.Checked, AccLedgerCheckBox.Checked, 
                               TrailCheckBox.Checked, PLCheckBox.Checked, 
                               AccReportsCheckBox.Checked, SmsCheckBox.Checked, 
                               EmailCheckBox.Checked, SmsReportsCheckBox.Checked, 
                               StockNavigationCheckBox.Checked);

          if (new LoginDAL().Save(login))
          {
             MessageBox.Show("User has been added successfully");
             REFRESH_FORM();
             T1.Text = Convert.ToString(md.Max_ID("UID", "LOGIN"));
          }
          else
          {
             MessageBox.Show("Not added try again");
          }

      }
      else {
             MessageBox.Show("Please enter into \'*\' empty fields");

           }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Source + ": " + ex.Message, "Connection Error !!");
   }
}
```

when i try to save then it will give an error Conversion failed when converting date/time from character string.

Comment: It's going to be something in the LoginTbl but it's impossible to tell without more information. Can you look at everything that's doing a Convert.ToDateTime( ) (DT1.Value for example) and see what the value is?

Comment: What is DT1 what type it is and when you get issue what exactly value it hold. Most probably the problem is looking into that area as it might hold wrong value which can't be converted into date time.

Comment: @PouyaSamie: i assume it's a `DateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DT1.Value.ToShortDateString())
```

you convert your DateTime to a string and then back to a date. This is not necessary. Remove both conversions and use `DT1.Value` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you convert the `DateTime` to `string` at all just to parse it back to `DateTime`? If you want to remove the time component from the date use [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

So instead of:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DT1.Value.ToShortDateString())
```

this

```
DT1.Value.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string-based date to a System.DateTime object, you can use the `Convert.ToDateTime(String)` method or the `DateTime.Parse(String)` static method

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DT1.Value.ToShortDateString())
```